# remote procedure call failed after deleting account

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Someone retired and we deleted an account associated with them on our Microsoft SQL Server 2008.  We are getting "remote procedure call failed 0x800706be" and the Administrator login is not working.  (And every thing else isn't working too)  It seems like somehow that account was a key for the whole Microsoft SQL Server install.

We tried restoring the Microsoft backup for C (windows) and D (applications/SQL Server) drives and it didn't fix it.  In fact, the deleted account didn't come back, although we had tried creating an account with the same name and hadn't deleted that fully before the restore.

Any ideas how to recover from that?  The rest of the server is like this:

F: our file system/web

G: DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-creating an account with the same name isn't going to work, because SQL Server uses the UID of the account and not the name for authentication.

Create a new Active Directory service account, and do a clean install of SQL Server using this new service account as the account to run SQL Server. Then, restore your database backups (including master, model, and msdb).

Comment: It turned out that we also changed the administrator password, and did a reboot after we deleted the other account.  The reboot caused the password change to take effect.  When we changed the password back, it fixed a lot of the issues.  Now we're still trying to deal with IIS issues.